# The button works on emulator but not on a real device

Tags: android, android-studio, datepicker, crash

Hello I am relatively new to android programming and I have a problem. When I run my app on emulator and press Datepicker the app runs smoothly but when I run it on my android device it stops working. Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static Context mContext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
    //---Setting property for greeting message and styling it a bit---//

    //---Initiallize properties for all of the buttons used in the Main Activity Page ---/
    ImageButton aquaButton;
    aquaButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bAquarius);
    ImageButton piscesButton;
    piscesButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bPisces);
    ImageButton ariesButton;
    ariesButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bAries);
    ImageButton taurusButton;
    taurusButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bTaurs);
    ImageButton geminiButton;
    geminiButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bGemini);
    ImageButton cancerButton;
    cancerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bCancer);
    ImageButton leoButton;
    leoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bLeo);
    ImageButton virgoButton;
    virgoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bVirgo);
    ImageButton libraButton;
    libraButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bLibra);
    ImageButton scorpioButton;
    scorpioButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bScorpio);
    ImageButton sagittariusButton;
    sagittariusButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bSagittarius);
    ImageButton capriButton;
    capriButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bCapricorn);

    //---Setting actions for each button when pressed---/

    aquaButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent aquaActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    aqua_Activity.class);
            startActivity(aquaActivity);
        }
    });
    piscesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent piscesActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    pisces_activity.class);
            startActivity(piscesActivity);
        }
    });
    ariesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent ariesActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    aries_activity.class);
            startActivity(ariesActivity);
        }
    });
    taurusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent taurusActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    taurus_activity.class);
            startActivity(taurusActivity);
        }
    });
    geminiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent geminiActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    gemini_activity.class);
            startActivity(geminiActivity);
        }
    });
    cancerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent cancerActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    cancer_activity.class);
            startActivity(cancerActivity);
        }
    });
    leoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent leoActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    leo_activity.class);
            startActivity(leoActivity);
        }
    });
    virgoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent virgoActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    virgo_activity.class);
            startActivity(virgoActivity);
        }
    });
    libraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent libraActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    libra_activity.class);
            startActivity(libraActivity);
        }
    });
    scorpioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent scorpioActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    scorpio_activity.class);
            startActivity(scorpioActivity);
        }
    });
    sagittariusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent sagittActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    sagittarius_activity.class);
            startActivity(sagittActivity);
        }
    });
    capriButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent capriActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    capricorn_activity.class);
            startActivity(capriActivity);
        }
    });


}
//--Initializing static methods for navigation--//
private static void goToCapriAct() {
    Intent capriacti = new Intent(mContext, capricorn_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(capriacti);
}
private static void goToAquaAct() {
    Intent aquaacti = new Intent(mContext, aqua_Activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(aquaacti);
}
private static void goToPiscAct() {
    Intent piscacti = new Intent(mContext, pisces_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(piscacti);
}
private static void goToAriesAct() {
    Intent ariesacti = new Intent(mContext, aries_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(ariesacti);
}
private static void goToTaurAct() {
    Intent taursacti = new Intent(mContext, taurus_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(taursacti);
}
private static void goToGeminiAct() {
    Intent geminiacti = new Intent(mContext, gemini_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(geminiacti);
}
private static void goToCancAct() {
    Intent cancacti = new Intent(mContext, cancer_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(cancacti);
}
private static void goToLeoAct() {
    Intent leoacti = new Intent(mContext, leo_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(leoacti);
}
private static void goToVirgoAct() {
    Intent virgoacti = new Intent(mContext, virgo_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(virgoacti);
}
private static void goToLibraAct() {
    Intent libraacti = new Intent(mContext, libra_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(libraacti);
}
private static void goToScorpAct() {
    Intent scorpacti = new Intent(mContext, scorpio_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(scorpacti);
}
private static void goToSaggAct() {
    Intent saggacti = new Intent(mContext, sagittarius_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(saggacti);
}

//--Setting DatePickerFragment--//
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

        int year = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance o f DatePickerDialog and return it
        int theme;
        theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog;
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), theme, this, year, month, day);

    }

    //--Checks about every single sign and navigation--//
    String message;
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        month = month + 1;
        if ((month == 12 && day >= 22 && day <= 31) || (month == 1 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)){
            goToCapriAct();
            }
        else if ((month == 1 && day >= 20 && day <= 31) || (month == 2 && day >= 1 && day <= 17)){
            goToAquaAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 2 && day >= 18 && day <= 29) || (month == 3 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
            goToPiscAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 3 && day >= 20 && day <= 31) || (month == 4 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
            goToAriesAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 4 && day >= 20 && day <= 30) || (month == 5 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
            goToTaurAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 5 && day >= 21 && day <= 31) || (month == 6 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
            goToGeminiAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 6 && day >= 21 && day <= 30) || (month == 7 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            goToCancAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 7 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 8 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            goToLeoAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 8 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 9 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            goToVirgoAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 9 && day >= 23 && day <= 30) || (month == 10 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            goToLibraAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 10 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 11 && day >= 1 && day <= 21)) {
            goToScorpAct();}
        else if ((month == 11 && day >= 22 && day <= 30) || (month == 12 && day >= 1 && day <= 21)) {
            goToSaggAct();}
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Illegal date");}
    }
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new MainActivity.DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}}
```

I`d be grateful if someone can explain to me why is that happening so I can avoid this mistake in future

Comment: `and press Datepicker`. I see no such element that you can press. Where are you talking about? And why post the code for a hundred buttons? If you are talking about a button then on!y the code for that button was enough. And why all those intents? Please remove irrelevant code.

Comment: OnDateSet is the function that act as a button